# 'IEnumerable<Alert>' does not contain a definition for 'Alert_Identifier' ... and 'IEnumerable<Alert>' does not contain a definition for 'AlertIndex'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've looked at numerous similar questions, but I'm still stuck. I have changed my Alert.cs class to inherit from IEnumerable, but that hasn't solved the problem when Visual Studio compiles the project to use Alert_Identifier and AlertIndex to populate a Select Tag Helper. Here's the Class.

```
Alert.cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace edxl_cap_v1_2.Models
{
    public class Alert : IEnumerable
{
    [Key]
    public int AlertIndex { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(150)]
    public string Alert_Identifier { get; set; }
    public string Sender { get; set; }
    public DateTime Sent { get; set; }
    public Status Status { get; set; }
    public MsgType MsgType { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public Scope Scope { get; set; }
    public string Restriction { get; set; }
    public string Addresses { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public string References { get; set; }
    public string Incidents { get; set; }
    public int DataCategory_Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Element> Elements { get; set; }

    public System.Collections.IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public enum Status
{
    Actual,
    Exercise,
    System,
    Test,
    Draft
}
public enum MsgType
{
    Alert,
    Update,
    Cancel,
    Ack,
    Error
}
public enum Scope
{
    Public,
    Restricted,
    Private
}
```

}

Here's where the errors occur in _CapCategoryLayout.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<edxl_cap_v1_2.Models.Alert>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/capv1_2_refimp.css" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Header -->
<header>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        @Html.Partial("_EdxlHeader")
    </div>
    @{
        <form asp-controller="EdxlCapMsg" asp-action="Index" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="alert-danger" asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
                <div class="content-wrapper">
                    <span class="smallText">
                        <label asp-for="Alert_Identifier" class="control-label"></label>
                        <select asp-for="AlertIndex" class="form-control"
                                asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.ListofIdentifier,"AlertIndex", "Alert_Identifier"))"></select>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="content-wrapper">
                    <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="content-wrapper">
                    @if (ViewBag.SelectedValue != null)
                    {
                        <text>Selected Alert_Identifier: </text> @ViewBag.SelectedValue;
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    }
</header>
<!-- End of Header -->

<!-- edxlLeftColumn -->
<div id="edxlLeftColumn">
    @Html.Partial("_CapLeftColumnPartial")
</div>
<!-- End of edxlLeftColumn -->
<!-- indexRightColumn-Content Body -->
<div id="indexRightColumn" style="position:relative">
    @RenderBody()
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</div>
<!-- End of edxlRightColumn-Content Body -->
<!-- Footer -->
<footer>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        @Html.Partial("_EdxlFooter")
    </div>
</footer>
```

Here's the Controller EdxlCapMsgController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using edxl_cap_v1_2.Data;
using edxl_cap_v1_2.Models;
using edxl_cap_v1_2.Models.ContentViewModels;

namespace edxl_cap_v1_2.Controllers
{
public class EdxlCapMsgController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public EdxlCapMsgController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: EdxlCapMessages
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        List<EdxlCapMsg> identifierlist = new List<EdxlCapMsg>();

        //------Getting Data fom Database using EntityFrameworkCore------
        identifierlist = (from product in _context.EdxlCapMsg
                          select product).ToList();

        //------Inserting Select Item in List------
        identifierlist.Insert(0, new EdxlCapMsg { Id = 0, Alert_Identifier = "Select" });

        //------Assigning countrylist to ViewBag.ListofCountry------
        ViewBag.ListofIdentifier = identifierlist;


        return View(await _context.EdxlCapMsg.ToListAsync());
    }

    [HttpPost]

    public IActionResult Index(EdxlCapMsg EdxlCapMsg)
    {
        //------Validation------
        if (EdxlCapMsg.Id == 0)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Select EdxlCapMsg");
        }

        //------Getting selected value------
        int SelectedValue = EdxlCapMsg.Id;

        ViewBag.SelectedValue = EdxlCapMsg.Id;

        //------Setting Data back to ViewBag after Posting form------
        List<EdxlCapMsg> identifierlist = new List<Models.EdxlCapMsg>();

        identifierlist = (from product in _context.EdxlCapMsg
                       select product).ToList();

        identifierlist.Insert(0, new EdxlCapMsg { Id = 0, Alert_Identifier = "Select" });
        ViewBag.ListofIdentifier = identifierlist;

        return View();
    }

}
```

I really thought that explicitly using ': IEnumerable' in Alert.cs would ensure that AlertIndex and Alert_Identifier would be included in IEnumerable. Please educate me why this isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Your view is strongly typed to `IEnumerable<YourClass>` and in your view you are passing the `AlertIndex` property of your view model to build the SELECT element with select tag helper. But `IEnumerable` collection does not have an `AlertIndex` property! Hence you are getting the error.

There is no need to inherit your `Alert` class from `IEnumerable`. Just remove that.

You should create a view model which has specific properties needed by your view. For rendering the SELECT element, add 2 properties, one for the selected option and one for the collection of items needed to build the SELECT Options.

```
public class MyListVm
{
   public string SelectedIdentifier { set;get;}
   public List<SelectListItem> Identifiers { set;get;}
   public List<AlertVm> Alerts { set;get;}
}
public class AlertVm
{
   public string Source { set;get;}
   public string Sender { set;get;} 
   // Add other properties needed by the view.
}
```

and in your GET action, you will create an object of this `MyListVm` class, populate the `Identifiers` collection property and `Alerts` property and send that to the view.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   var vm = new MyListVm();

   //Load the Identifiers property which will be used to build the SELECT element
   vm.Identifiers = _context.EdxlCapMsg
                           .Select(x=>new SelectListItem { Value =x.Id.ToString(),
                                                           Text=x.Name}).ToList();

   //Load the Alerts
   vm.Alerts = _context.EdxlCapMsg.Select(a=>new AlertVm {
                                Source = a.Source,
                                Sender = a.Sender }).ToList();
   return View(vm);
}
```

Now make sure your view is strongly typed to this view model. You can use `Model.Alerts` expression to get the Alert collection.

```
@model MyListVm
<h2>@Model.Alerts.Count alerts</h2>
<form>
    <select asp-for="SelectedAlertIndex" asp-items="@Model.AlertOptions">
        <option>Select one</option>
    </select>
    <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Make necessary changes (in terms of property names) to make it work for your use case. Also the code you shared in the question does not seems to use the list of `Alert` objects. So if you do not render it, do not query it at all!

Comment: I hit a snag when listing properties in second part of the Controller fot GET Alerts because I have three properties, Status, MsgType, and  Scope  that are enums with message "Cannot implicitly convert type 'edxl_cap...Models.Status' to 'edxl_cap ...ContentViewModels.Status' An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Also, I'm so wrapped up in getting the select list to work that I neglected to say that the selected value for Alert_Identifiers selects the Alert DataCategory for the overall message identified by Alert_Identifier. Ialso have to do this for the Area, Info and Resource Categories before combining all data categories together into the final overall message. So I'm working on just the most important data category, Alert to be the model for the rest.

Comment: For the error ""Cannot implicitly convert type 'edxl_cap...Models.Status' to 'edxl_cap ...ContentViewModels.Status' An explicit conversion exists", Make sure your types are same. Also like i mentioned, you do not need to copy your entity model as it is to the view model. Use only properties needed by view (if it only needs the status name, just add a string property called status name to the  view model

Comment: I made a new view model based on your example, and changed the controller per example, and made a new view just for this select tag helper with similar but not identical names, and I'm getting NullReferenceException on the line: <select asp-for="SelectedIdentifier" asp-items="(at)Model.Alert_Identifiers"> Seems like its not connecting to database alert table where I have 3 records.

Comment: What is `Alert_Identifiers` ? My answer does not have such a property on the view model.

Comment: Alert_Identifiers are strings such as 'NOAA-NWS-ALERTS-CA-125838fsecfc.WinterStormWarning.125838f803c0CA-.EKAWSWEKA.d2e18d2b81b08f7bcd9e6fadde0ff6db'-These are generated by CAP users such as NOAA-NWS. Essentially uuids. These are independent of individual systems that might have their own ids for in house housekeeping. CAP refers to the Common Alerting Protocol an OASIS IT standard for alerts and warnings. These are system-independent identifiers for CAP Alert Messages. I'm working on a reference implementation of CAP, as the first of the Emergency Data Exchange Language (EDXL) Specifications.

Comment: @AlertOptions didn't refer to anything specific in your example so I took it as description for items in question and Alert_Identifiers are those items, one per CAP message.

Comment: I meant @Model.AlertOptions.

Comment: The approach& code shared in answer should solve your problem. Try it

Comment: My comment saying it worked got deleted. Thanks. Now I need to use the selected item to load /alerts/index.cshtml view page with form filled in with values from record where Alert_Identifier equals SelectedAlertIndex. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Go ahead and do that.What is stopping you ?

Comment: I meant 'Now I need to use the selected item to load /alerts/index.cshtml view page with form filled in with values from record where AlertIndex equals SelectedAlertIndex.' Sample code to do something like this with Submit Button would be very helpful e.g. <a href=./alert/index.cshtml></a> but how to add 'where AlertIndex equals SelectedAlertIndex'?  A link to a sample would be good, too.

Comment: That is totally different than what your original question is. What you are asking is basically querying data. I suggest you to learn the basics with tutorials online (learn.microsoft.com has some good tutorials. I do not think anyone is going to write code for you. You should try some code yourself and when you are stuck with an error, ask a question.

Comment: Thanks @Shyju for the help. What you describe is what I'm doing as best I can. I've spent numerous hours looking at similar questions about Submit actions , but haven't found an example even close to what my next challenge is, but I'll keep trying.

Comment: You should not be asking new questions in comments. Open a new question with relevant details (errors you are encountering etc).